# Uncaught Reference Error: Firebase is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following piece of code I'm trying to use to authenticate a newly registered user, although it fails to even initialize firebase, popping up this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: firebase is not defined

Below is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>register</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src='https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.4.2/firebase.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var config = {
            databaseURL: 'https://apcs-4bfaa.firebaseio.com/'
        };
        firebase.initializeApp(config);

        var ref = new Firebase("https://apcs-4bfaa.firebaseio.com/");

        function registerUser() {
            var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
            var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
            ref.auth().createNewUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
        }
    </script>

    <div class="form">
        <div id="error"></div>
        <form onsubmit="registerUser();">
            <label>Email:</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email"><br>
            <label>Password:</label>
            <input type="password" name="pwd" id="password"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Sign Up"><br>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The [Web Quickstart](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/quickstart.html) does not show any reference to a `firebase` object and all it seems to accomplish is defining the same URL twice. Doesn't `new Firebase()` do it all?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález There is a new `SDK` that includes the `firebase` object. Check out https://firebase.google.com

Comment: You're using fairly old documentation. Be sure to use the latest (for any framework) to make sure everything is working correctly. @DavidEast has the right answer.

Comment: @AlanThomas It says ref.auth() is not a function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code is mixed up between the older `2.4.2` API and the the `3.0` SDK.

There are no more `new Firebase()` calls. You need to use the new SDK, currently `3.0.3`, and then configure your app.

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.0.3/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: '<your-api-key>',
    authDomain: '<your-auth-domain>',
    databaseURL: '<your-database-url>',
    storageBucket: '<your-storage-bucket>'
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>
```

After configuring you can then create references.

```
firebase.database().ref()
```

So in your case it would be:

```
<script>
    var config = {
        databaseURL: 'https://apcs-4bfaa.firebaseio.com/'
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);

    // new 3.0 SDK method!
    var ref = firebase.database().ref();

    function registerUser() {
        var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
        var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
        firebase.auth().createNewUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
    }
</script>
```

[**Check out the docs for more info.**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#add_firebase_to_your_app)

Comment: No. It says ref.auth() is not a function.

Comment: Sorry I copied and pasted the code from your sample. It needed to be updated to `firebase.auth()` not `ref.auth()`.